# Uncaught TypeError: getElementsByName is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of elements on a page that are formatted like below:

```
<div class="longdesc">
 <pre style="...">
   //stuff here
 </pre>
</div>
<div class="longdesc">
 <pre style="...">
   //stuff here
 </pre>
</div>
```

I'm trying to replace some of the content inside the `<pre>` tag but I'm having trouble.

```
(function () {    
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("longdesc");
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        var node = nodes[n].getElementsByName("pre");
        node[0].textContent = node[0].textContent.replace("<", "&lt;");
        //other code
    }
})();
```

> VM5185:4 Uncaught TypeError: nodes[n].getElementsByName is not a
>   function

I only need the first `pre` in each `longdesc`.  How can I do this?

Comment: You need `.getElementsByTagName("pre");`

Comment: please post as answer...

Comment: See the reason why https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055419/560287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getElementsByTagName()` instead.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
(function () {    
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("longdesc");
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        var node = nodes[n].getElementsByTagName("pre");
        node[0].textContent = node[0].textContent.replace("<", "&lt;");
        //other code
    }
})();
```