# form.getElementsByName is not a function, but document.getElementsByName is

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

This first example (`type="button"` is intentional) should work:

```html
<form class="needs-submission">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" name="save" value="Save Changes" onclick="saveChanges(this.closest('.needs-submission'))">
</form>
```

```js
function saveChanges(form) {
    const id = document.getElementsByName('id')[0]
    const name = document.getElementsByName('name')[0]
    const save = document.getElementsByName('save')[0]
}
```

However, when I want to select the same fields from the perspective of the `form` rather than the whole `document`, `form.getElementsByName` is not recognised as a function.

```js
function saveChanges(form) {
    const id = form.getElementsByName('id')[0]
    const name = form.getElementsByName('name')[0]
    const save = form.getElementsByName('save')[0]
}
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: form.getElementsByName is not a function
    at saveChanges
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

But `form.getElementsByTagName` seems works fine?

```js
function saveChanges(form) {
    const id = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
    const name = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[1]
    const save = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[2]
}
```

My question is: Why can't I get the fields by their `name` attribute? Do `document` and `form` have different datatypes?

Comment: Yes, [`Document.protoype.getElementsByName`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) exists; a method with the same name does not exist on the [`HTMLElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) prototype. Try `querySelector` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know there was a difference. `querySelector` does the trick for me, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MDN, getElementsByName is a function of the Document object (so it only exists for the global document object, not for every HTML element): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

As a workaround, you could use a query selector to find the element like this:

```
const name = form.querySelector("input[name='name']");
```